# Android NavigationDrawer items don't click

Tags: android

I'm using Android NavigationDrawer without `Listview` items into slide menu, after creating and changing that slide menu items don't click and don't work to handle to click, for example this below code is my XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/create_new_waybill"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:clickable="true">
                        <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_add_waybill"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                        <com.sample.app.Widgets.TextViewStyle
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
                                android:text="@string/slidemenu_waybill"
                                app:fonttype="mjbeirut"
                                android:textColor="#000000"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainViewFragments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In this XML I want to show `Toast` after clicking on `create_new_waybill` id.

**my Activity**

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout mSlideMenuContainer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[]              items;
    private UiFiller              uiFiller;
    private int                   currentSelectedSlideMenuItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        G.currentActivity = this;
        /* Getting reference to the DrawerLayout */
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mSlideMenuContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slide_menu);
        LinearLayout create_new_waybill = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.create_new_waybill);

        create_new_waybill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("ffffffffffff","aaaaaaa");
            }
        });
        /* Initials UI widgets */
        uiFiller = new UiFiller(getWindow().getDecorView());

        /* Setting default fragment */
        currentSelectedSlideMenuItem = 0;

        updateFragment(currentSelectedSlideMenuItem);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these 3 attributes for `ImageView` and `TextViewStyle`:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

and replace `Log.e("ffffffffffff","aaaaaaa");`

with:

`Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: `create_new_waybill` is linear layout sir, i'm testing your code, dont resolve problem

Comment: Then my best guess is that under navigation drawer you have view that gains focus when you click on your layout. `EditText` for instance.